# Indexes when using LET statement

Tags: orientdb

Consider two vertices, one called Crash and one called GenericCarModel. The Crash vertex has a property called carModel which is a String. The GenericCarModel vertex has a property called name which has been indexed as GenericCarModel.nameHash.

I am interested in finding the carModels that exists in the Crash Vertex but has not yet been added to the GenericCarModel by comparing the names. Basically the filled in part of this venn diagram: [image]

Also assume in this particular example we have a lot more models in the GenericCarModel than CarModels that have crashed.

I've tried the following approach:

```
SELECT FROM Crash WHERE $all.size() = 0 
LET $all = 
    (SELECT FROM GenericCarModel 
    WHERE name = $parent.$current.carModel LIMIT 1)
```

This is approach works but is really slow. Let's use the index:

```
SELECT FROM Crash WHERE $all.size() = 0 
LET $all = 
    (SELECT FROM index:CarModel.nameHash 
    WHERE key = $parent.$current.carModel LIMIT 1)
```

This doesn't work.

So two questions, why is the index approach not working? My approach doesn't seem optimal, how would you approach it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're ignoring the graph features of your graphdb! I would remodel this so that you have:

- Car extends V
- Incident extends V
- Crash extends E

When something bad happens, you create an Incident vertex with the details. You then create a Crash edge from the Incident to the Car.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm quite aware that I am. It will be changed in the future I hope but for now I'm stuck with this. Oh well, thanks anyways!